# Handling authentication when embedding PowerBI Report Server reports

Tags: .net, authentication, reporting-services, webbrowser-control, powerbi

I am trying to embed a report, hosted on a PowerBI Report Server, into a `WebBrowser` control.

I use url of the following form:

`reportserver.server.com/reports/powerbi/TestReport?rs:embed=true`
(["Capturing the URL parameter" section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/quickstart-embed))

This works, however prompts for Active Directory authentication,
through a browser:

[image: Authentication Required]

in my application:

[image: Windows Security]

If I enter credentials everything works. However, I would like to authenticate programmatically.
Including credentials in the url like so:
`user:password@reportserver.server.com/reports/powerbi/TestReport?rs:embed=true`
works in a browser, however displays a confirmation dialog:

[image: You are about to log in to the site]

In the WebBrowser of the application, however, it does not, and shows this instead:

[image: GLOBAL_ERRORS.SERVICE_TITLE** GLOBAL_ERRORS.TIMEOUT**]

This page is loaded instantly. The link is `https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=847142` ("Configure a Report Server Database Connection (SSRS Configuration Manager)"). I think the article is not relevant.

Is there a way of authenticating programmatically without disabling authentication on the Report Server?

My code is trivial:

```
var url = new Uri(@"user:password@reportserver.server.com/reports/powerbi/TestReport?rs:embed=true");
webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
```

Trying to pass credentials in a header results in a blank page and seemingly nothing happening:

```
var url = new Uri(@"reportserver.server.com/reports/powerbi/TestReport?rs:embed=true");
string auth = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
string headers = "Authorization: Basic " + auth + "\r\n";
webBrowser1.Navigate(url, "", null, headers);
```

Answer (score 2):

Found an ugly workaround, posting in case someone else finds this useful, however won't accept this as an answer as would still prefer a "clean" solution.

It works if you first navigate to the url with credentials, then url without ones:

```
private string justUrl { get { return urlPrefix + url; } }
private string urlWithCreds { get { return urlPrefix + username + ":" + password + "@" + url ; } }
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var url1 = new Uri(urlWithCreds);
    webBrowser1.Navigated += WebBrowser1_Navigated; // one-time
    webBrowser1.Navigate(url1);
}
private void WebBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigated -= WebBrowser1_Navigated;
    webBrowser1.Navigate(justUrl);
}
```